# Add additional row for each rows with a different value for a specific column

Tags: sql, azure-sql-database

I want to add a new row for each existing rows. The new row will contain a new value for one of the column and same values for the remaining columns.

From the below table, I want to add a new 'ADUser' -> 'manju@apac.corpdir.net' for each 'Tag' value. Lets say, the current number of rows are 4. After the operation, the final number of rows should be 8.

I have been experimenting with some INSERT queries, but I am unsuccessful. Any help is highly appreciated.

Database: Azure SQL Database

Current Table Rows :

[image]

Expected Table Rows:

[image]

Comment: If two two consecutie Tags already exists, do you want a duplicated tag to be generated?

Comment: Sorry, the TAG value should be the same. I have update the question

Comment: Then it's pretty simple...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `insert`:

```
insert into t (id, tag, aduser)
    select id, t.tag, 'manju@apac.corpdir.net' 
    from t;
```

I am guessing that `created` is assigned automatically.  If not, you could use:

```
insert into t (id, tag, aduser, created)
    select t.tag, 'manju@apac.corpdir.net', current_timestamp
    from t;
```

It seems odd that you want duplicate values for `id`, but that is what the question is asking for.  This should really identify each row uniquely and be assigned automatically.

Comment: OP wants tag value to be increased as well.

Comment: Sorry, the TAG value should be the same. I have update the question.